# Getting customized message from GCM using Web push notifications

Tags: web-push, push-api, progressive-web-apps

I'm using Web push notifications with Chrome, and they work great. But now I want to deliver a custom message in my notifications.  I can have my Service Worker call out to my site to get content, as is done at https://simple-push-demo.appspot.com/—which is fine if I want every recipient to see the same message.

Is there any way to get either the recipient’s `registration_id` or the `message_id` that GCM returns? If I could get either of these and include them in the callback to the service, I could customize the response.

Also, any info on when we might be able to include a payload in the call to GCM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `registration_id` and `message_id` fields aren't exposed, but if the user is previously authenticated to your app, any `fetch()` to the server from your Service Worker will include credentials (and session information) which you can use to identify them.

If that doesn't work for your case, you can store user/session information in IndexedDB.

Payloads are coming soon—likely Chrome 50 or 51—based on the Web Push protocol. It's a bit of extra overhead and work to configure the (required) encryption.

Comment: I send 2 messages to `user A`: `m1` and `m2`. On the client, I receive  2 messages without any info. I can tell the server that I'm `user A`, but how does server know if it should return information for `m1` or for `m2`?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but I wouldn't do it since it's specific to GCM, while other browsers use other services.

You can either create a unique ID for each user (like we're doing in [Mercurius](https://github.com/marco-c/mercurius)) and store it in IndexedDB, or you can use the entire endpoint URL as an ID.

Here's the snippet to get the `registration_id`:

```
self.registration.pushManager.getSubscription()
.then(function(subscription) {
  if (subscription) {
    var endpoint = subscription.endpoint;
    var endpointParts = endpoint.split('/');
    var gcmRegistrationID = endpointParts[endpointParts.length - 1];

    console.log(gcmRegistrationID);
  }
});
```

P.S.: It returns a promise, so make sure your service worker waits for the promise to be resolved.